How to prove the question about dual pair of Banach space?
Definition: Two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ form a dual pair $\langle X,Y\rangle$ if there is a bilinear or a sesquilinear  form $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ on $X\times Y$ which satisfies the following properties:

$|\langle u,v\rangle|\leq c\|u\|_X\|v\|_Y$.
$\|u\|_{X} \leq c_{1} \sup_{v\in Y}\frac{|\langle u,v\rangle |}{\|v\|_{Y}}$ for all $u\in X$.
$\|v\|_{X}\leq c_{1} \sup_{u\in Y}\frac{|\langle u,v\rangle |}{\|u\|_{X}}$ for all $v\in Y$.

A sesquilinear form $\langle u,v\rangle$ is a complex valued function on $X\times Y$ which is linear in $u$ and conjugate linear in $v$.
Now I want to prove the follow question:
Suppose $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is a dual pair of Banach spaces, $Z$ is a dense linear subspace of $Y$, and $f$ is a continuous function from a compact interval $[a,b]$ to $X$. Then there exists a Borel function $g$ from $[a,b]$ to $Z$ such that $\|g(t)\|_{Y} = 1$ for all $t$ and $\|f(t)\|_{X} \leq 2c_{1}\langle f(t),g(t)\rangle $ for all $t$.
I have no idea about the question.

You can edit the notation like the first bullet.

You are right. Than you
